# squid proxy url_regex with ssl-bump

Tags: ubuntu, squid

I've been banging my head trying to get squid proxy to work with https.
I've checked that its supported and enabled ssl-bumping.
I've also setup the certificates etc according to https://support.kaspersky.com/KWTS/6.1/en-US/166244.htm but it still isn't working.

If I have the following it works:
acl blacklist_ssl ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/blacklist.acl"
http_access deny blacklist_ssl

However the fact that my url_regex isn't working suggests something is still wrong with ssl-bump

My configure options are ('--with-openssl' '--enable-ssl-crtd'):

```
Squid Cache: Version 5.2
Service Name: squid
Ubuntu linux

This binary uses OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020. For legal restrictions on distribution see https://www.openssl.org/source/license.html

configure options:  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' 'BUILDCXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/builder/ubuntu20/build/squid/squid-5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ' 'BUILDCXX=g++' '--with-build-environment=default' '--enable-build-info=Ubuntu linux' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/squid' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--enable-inline' '--disable-arch-native' '--enable-async-io=8' '--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock' '--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,NCSA,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB' '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP' '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper' '--enable-auth-ntlm=fake,SMB_LM' '--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,time_quota,unix_group,wbinfo_group' '--enable-security-cert-validators=fake' '--enable-storeid-rewrite-helpers=file' '--enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake' '--enable-eui' '--enable-esi' '--enable-icmp' '--enable-zph-qos' '--enable-ecap' '--disable-translation' '--with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid' '--with-logdir=/var/log/squid' '--with-pidfile=/run/squid.pid' '--with-filedescriptors=65536' '--with-large-files' '--with-default-user=proxy' '--enable-linux-netfilter' '--with-systemd' '--with-openssl' '--enable-ssl-crtd' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/builder/ubuntu20/build/squid/squid-5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/builder/ubuntu20/build/squid/squid-5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
```

And my squid.conf is and I'm expecting the simple url https://bitbucket.org/ to be blocked:

```
acl intermediate_fetching transaction_initiator certificate-fetching
http_access allow intermediate_fetching
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
http_access allow localhost
acl test url_regex -i ^https://bitbucket.org/*
http_access deny test
http_access allow all
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump peek all
ssl_bump splice all
ssl_bump bump all
http_port 3128 ssl-bump tcpkeepalive=60,30,3 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=20MB tls-cert=/etc/squid/bump.crt tls-key=/etc/squid/bump.key cipher=HIGH:MEDIUM:!LOW:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS tls-dh=prime256v1:/etc/squid/bump_dhparam.pem

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 20MB
sslproxy_cert_error deny all
ssl_bump stare all
```

Then in my logs I see (which says it should work?):

```
Apr 03 07:15:42 ip-10-2-0-210 squid[29510]: Accepting SSL bumped HTTP Socket connections at conn13 local=[::]:3128 remote=[::] FD 23 flags=9
```

I'm running Ubuntu20.04 and squid version 5.2
Can anyone see whats wrong here?

## Update

Ok I kind've got this working now by:

```
ssl_bump bump ssl_force_bump
ssl_bump bump all
```

However, I'm still not getting the behaviour I want.
If I have:

```
acl whitelist url_regex ^http(s)://bitbucket.org/products
acl blacklist url_regex ^http(s)://bitbucket.org/*

http_access allow whitelist 
http_access deny !whitelist blacklist
```

It's now blacklisting everything for https://bitbucket.org

How would I only blacklist a subset of urls for https://bitbucket.org